# R: Print omitted 0's in table() - contingency tables

Tags: r, contingency

I use large sets of contingency tables by looping table(). 
Simple problem: columns containing only 0's are omitted in the output.
Can this be adjusted using table()?

Example:

data

```
1 0
0 0
1 0
0 0
0 0
1 0
1 0
1 0
1 0
```

The output I get:

```
table(data)
    0
  0 3
  1 6
```

The output I need:

```
    0 1
  0 3 0
  1 6 0
```

Thanks.

Comment: Here's one way: `data2 <- data; data2[] <- lapply(data,factor,levels=as.character(0:1)); table(data2)` I suspect this question was asked before; going to take a look.

Comment: @Frank your comment is an answer. You should add it as an answer. That way Stackoverflow works best.

Comment: @JesperRønn-Jensen Should I answer even if it's a dupe?

Comment: @Frank if you can find a dupe, vote to close as such.

Comment: Still looking. Top candidate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5558745/1191259

Comment: @Frank: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8461140/3005513) is the closest.

Comment: @AlexA. Hm, I still lean towards the other one (since we have to modify multiple dimensions of the `table`) and can't switch my own vote now, besides. Other voters'll see both suggested dupes, though, and can consider it. By the way, you can edit your auto-generated flag-as-dupe comment (e.g., to @ someone or edit the text).

Comment: @Frank Your answer (first comment) works perfectly, thanks.